# no viable overloaded '=' for overloaded static member functions

Tags: c++, static, assignment-operator, std-function

I have this simplified code consisting of a class with a static function, which is stored in map:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <map>

class A {
public:
  static void f(const std::string &s) { std::cout << s; }
}; 

std::map<std::string, std::function<void(std::string const &)>> fs; 

int main() {
  fs["f"] = &A::f;
  fs["f"]("hello");
}
```

This prints the expected *hello*.

The problem occurs if I overload f() with:

```
 static void f(const std::string &s, int c) { while(c-->0) { std::cout << s; } }
```

This results in the error:

```
 error: no viable overloaded '='
   fs["f"] = &A::f;
   ~~~~~~~ ^ ~~~~~
 /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../../include/c++/4.9/functional:2241:7: note: candidate function not viable: no overload of 'f' matching 'const std::function<void (const std::basic_string<char> &)>' for 1st argument
       operator=(const function& __x)
       ^
 /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../../include/c++/4.9/functional:2259:7: note: candidate function not viable: no overload of 'f' matching 'std::function<void (const std::basic_string<char> &)>' for 1st argument
       operator=(function&& __x)
       ^
 /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../../include/c++/4.9/functional:2273:7: note: candidate function not viable: no overload of 'f' matching 'nullptr_t' for 1st argument
       operator=(nullptr_t)
       ^
 /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../../include/c++/4.9/functional:2302:2: note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument '_Functor'
       operator=(_Functor&& __f)
       ^
 /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../../include/c++/4.9/functional:2311:2: note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument '_Functor'
       operator=(reference_wrapper<_Functor> __f) noexcept
       ^
```

However, calling both functions works:

```
A::f("hello ");
A::f("echo ", 3);
```

So, my question are:

1. Why this code not compiling even though the operator= seems to exist and function if I don't overload f()?
2. How can I get it to work without giving both functions different names?

Comment: `#include <string>`?

Comment: 1. because the function is overloaded, 2. `fs["f"] = static_cast<void(*)(std::string const &)>(&A::f);`

Comment: @PiotrS. Your suggestion does work. Can you explain why/how it works?

Comment: The alternative to manually selecting the overload is to use a lambda: `fs["f"] = [](std::string const& s) { A::f(s); };`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why this code not compiling even though the operator= seems to exist
>   and function if I don't overload f()?

Because the compiler doesn't know which overload to choose. How could he? There is no criterion upon which he can decide which one is suited better. Every `std::function` allows arbitrary function objects to be assigned and doesn't check *any* signatures. If you wanted to save only function pointers of this particular signature you should have declared the `map` appropriately.

> How can I get it to work without giving both functions different
>   names?

As already mentioned it works by casting the expression to a function pointer of the specific type.

```
fs["f"] = static_cast<void(*)(std::string const&)>( &A::f );
```

This way no ambiguities arise; There is exactly one overload that can be casted to this function to pointer type.
 If this appears more often then a typedef could be feasible.

Or a little helper class template:

```
template <typename... Exact>
struct funptr
{
    template <typename R>
    constexpr auto operator()(R(*p)(Exact...)) -> decltype(p)
    { return p; }
};

fs["f"] = funptr<std::string const&>()(&A::f);
```

[**Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e1044c0cf2993474).